# For XML PATH change location

Tags: xml, t-sql, powershell

I have a query like

```
SELECT ProductModelID AS "@id", Name 
  FROM Production.ProductModel 
  WHERE ProductModelID=122 or ProductModelID=119  
  FOR XML PATH ('ProductModelData'), root ('Root');  
GO
```

and it works very well, but the thing is I want to create a task with PowerShell to create an XML file, but I can't tell where to store the file.

Comment: How are you executing the SQL?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to create XML document. But the best way is to use the **XMLTextWriter class**

```
$xmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter('C:\Cars.xml',$Null)

$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()

$xmlWriter.WriteComment('Value')
```

Go through the link for reference.

[XML Document Creation](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Using-PowerShell-to-create-XML-documents)

Alternative ways:

[XML Creation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2007/05/29/using-powershell-to-generate-xml-documents/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BCP` to write the result of a SQL query to the file system:

```
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(50)='C:\YourPath\test.xml';
DECLARE @SQLCmd   VARCHAR(500)= 
                  'bcp ' 
                + '"SELECT ProductModelID AS "@id", Name ' 
                + 'FROM Production.ProductModel ' 
                + 'WHERE ProductModelID=122 or ProductModelID=119 '  
                + 'FOR XML PATH (''ProductModelData''), root (''Root'')"' 
                + ' queryout '  
                + @FileName 
                + ' -w -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME;

-- create the XML file
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd
```